# Showing Database Content in a Certain View on a Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Ok so here is what am thinking. Am making a recruitment website to hire people. It gives a functionality to the applicant that he can build his cv online! i have made various forms for that.

After filling the forms the applicant will submit the information to database and then am saving all of the information from the webpages related to building cv in the database!

Am thinking of providing the applicant a tab on which when he clicks "View CV" and i show him the cv he built on a new web page in the format like this

http://careers.telenor.com.pk/Page/Detail/VacancyView.aspx?PositionID=3003265

Like the fields should be on the left as table columns and their respective content in the database on the right! Can anybody completely guide me how i can do that ?? or direct me to a specific tutorial ?? i would be grateful! Am using Asp.net!

I have seen grid view! Much like a table it is! with columns on the top and below the values in the database! That is not the thing i want!

Answer (score 0):

DetailsView control can be used to display fields from a single data record. It has that "format" you are looking for.

You can find documentation in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w1w7t4.aspx